# Replace text in a file after nth line till the end of file in unix

Tags: sed, replace

I have a file

## File.txt

```
LV_A=1;  
LV_B=2;  
LV_C=rr;  
jfffkf LV_A dndd LV_B  
hjhf LV_C  
hjhf LV_Chjhf LV_C  
hjhf LV_C  
hjhf LV_C  
hjhf LV_C  
etc
```

i will create file call replcae.txt

```
LV_A,1  
LV_B,2  
LV_C,rr
```

so need to find with column 1 of replace.txt and replace the file.txt with matching column 2 from repalce.txt but  from or after 4th in file.txt.

can you please provide a solution.

when i try with global command,its replacing full file

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format the examples as code so we can read them easily, ii) show us the output you are expecting from your example input, iii) make sure your file names are consistent to avoid confusion (you mention `File.txt` and `file.txt` and then `repalce.txt` and `replcae.txt`).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`while IFS="," read -r a b ; do sed -i '4,$'"s/$a/$b/g" files.txt;done <replcae.txt`
Input:

```
LV_A=1;
LV_B=2;
LV_C=rr;
jfffkf LV_A dndd LV_B
hjhf LV_C
hjhf LV_Chjhf LV_C
hjhf LV_C
hjhf LV_C
hjhf LV_C
etc
```

Output:

```
LV_A=1;
LV_B=2;
LV_C=rr;
jfffkf 1 dndd 2
hjhf rr
hjhf rrhjhf rr
hjhf rr
hjhf rr
hjhf rr
etc
files.txt (END)
```

First time I forget the g....